# hangfire in worker error some time after so (1 or 2 worker working)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, hangfire, hangfire-sql

Hangfire in worker count error
there are 700 job in Enqueue and 36 worker counts available and 36 process are processing
than add more job 500 in another Queues than worker are than working
properly 1 to 2 hour than worker are not free they only show 1 or 2 worker available and only select 1 or 2 process at time than more data add take to much time

If I am restart server or application so working properly and processing job very fast and all worker are working than some time see same issue in hangfire